# How to implement a GemFire CacheListener in Spring Boot using Spring Boot for Pivotal GemFire Starter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-gemfire

May I know how to implement a GemFire/Geode `CacheListener` in my *Spring Boot* application?

I want to detect delete and update in my "People" Region. I using org.springframework.data:spring-data-gemfire dependency in Maven. Do I need to include any annotation?

```
@SpringBootApplication  
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "AccessingDataGemFireApplication", logLevel = "error")
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = People.class)
@EnableGemfireRepositories  
public class Application
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the more convenient `@EnableEntityDefinedRegions` SDG annotation (which is recommended, especially for simple UC), then you do not explicitly define a Region bean definition (e.g. using SDG's `ReplicationRegionFactoryBean` or `PartitionedRegionFactoryBean` classes) as **Juan Ramos** did in his answer.

In this case, you can declare a [`RegionConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/RegionConfigurer.html) to modify the "People" Region and then apply the same technique **Juan** did from his answer to supply the `CacheListener`.

For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = People.class)
@EnableGemfireRepositories(..)
class MySpringBootGemFireApplication {

  @Bean
  RegionConfigurer peopleRegionConfigurer(
      CacheListener<Long, Person> peopleRegionListener) {

    return new RegionConfigurer() {

      @Override
      public void configure(String beanName, 
          ClientRegionFactoryBean<Long, Person> regionFactory) {

        regionFactoryBean.setCacheListeners(
          new CacheListener[] { peopleRegionListener });
    };
  }

  @Bean
  CacheListenerAdapter<Long, Person> peopleRegionListener() {

    return new CacheListenerAdapter<>() {

        public void afterDestroy(EntryEvent<Long, Person> event) { ... }

        public void afterUpdate(EntryEvent<Long, Person> event) { ... }
    };
  }
}
```

NOTE: when using the Spring Boot, GemFire Starter (`org.springframework.geode:spring-gemfire-starter`), the `@ClientCacheApplication` annotation is definitely not required since SBDG auto-configures a `ClientCache` instance by default (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#geode-clientcache-applications)).

NOTE: Additionally, if your application `GemfireRepositories` are in a sub-package below the main Spring Boot application class, you also do not need to explicitly declare the `@EnableGemfireRepositories` since SBDG auto-configures the SD Repository infrastructure for you (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#geode-repositories)).

For more information on SDG Configurers, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-configurers).

Hope this helps.

Comment: When i try your solution, my compiler gave me this "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" on the line "return (beanName, regionFactoryBean)". Since it is default method. I think Lambdas don't allow overriding default methods. Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: My apologies.  Actually, it is because the `RegionConfigurer` interface (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/RegionConfigurer.html) is not a `FunctionalInterface`. The interface defines 2 default methods, 1 with the `ClientRegionFactoryBean` to define client Regions and another with the `PeerRegionFactoryBean` when defining server Regions. Therefore, you must be exact about which method you are "overriding", and as such, the _Lambda) does not work for this interface unlike other SDG provided `Configurers`.

Comment: I corrected my example above.  You can see another example of the `RegionConfigurer` in SDG's test suite, here (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/RegionConfigurerIntegrationTests.java#L185-L203).  Technically, you only need to override 1 of the 2 methods depending on whether your application is a "client" or an actual "peer" in the cluster.  Given you are using `@ClientCacheApplication`, then you would override the client method as my modified example shows above.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there's still no annotation support for GemFire callbacks (`CacheListener`, `CacheLoader`, etc.) in the latest GA release of `spring-data-gemfire`. The JIRA ticket [SGF-453](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-453) was created some time ago to implement this enhancement, you can add yourself as a *watcher* to get updates about the progress.

You can, however, manually associate a `CacheListener` to a region using the `cache-listener` xml element, as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:region:cache-listener). Or, yet another option, you can configure the listener directly through the API using [`RegionFactoryBean.setListeners`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/2.0.10.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/RegionFactoryBean.html#setCacheListeners-org.apache.geode.cache.CacheListener:A-).

As an example, the following class starts a local GemFire server with an embedded locator, creates a `REPLICATED` region named `People` and associates a custom `CacheListener` to it, which basically prints out a message every time an entry is created or deleted:

```
@EnableLogging
@EnableStatistics
@SpringBootApplication
@CacheServerApplication
public class GemFireServerApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GemFireServerApplication.class, args);
  }

  @EnableLocator
  @Profile("!clustered")
  @EnableManager(start = true)
  @Configuration
  static class LonerConfiguration { }

  @Bean("People")
  public ReplicatedRegionFactoryBean<?, ?> replicatedRegion(GemFireCache gemfireCache) {
    ReplicatedRegionFactoryBean<?, ?> replicatedRegion = new ReplicatedRegionFactoryBean<>();
    replicatedRegion.setCache(gemfireCache);
    replicatedRegion.setClose(false);
    replicatedRegion.setPersistent(false);
    replicatedRegion.setCacheListeners(new CacheListener[] { myCacheListener() });

    return replicatedRegion;
  }

  @Bean
  public CacheListener<?, ?> myCacheListener() {
    return new CacheListenerAdapter<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public void afterDestroy(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
        System.out.println(String.format("AfterDestroy invoked for key %s !", event.getKey()));
        super.afterDestroy(event);
      }

      @Override
      public void afterCreate(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
        System.out.println(String.format("AfterCreate invoked for key %s !", event.getKey()));
        super.afterCreate(event);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.